# Asynchronous client cert verification in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I need to implement following the high level logic:

- A client set SNI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to show to which "server" it wants to connects
- A server will request a client cert authentication
- A client will send a client cert (it has just one which it will send)
- We don't have a CA cert locally at that moment (which is most important piece of info) and we need to go and asynchronously get one
- We should verify the client cert when we retrieved CA cert.

I know how to implement all of this functionality in a synchronous mode (when I have CA cert locally or just block everything until I get one) using: `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback`, `SSL_CTX_set_verify`, `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`

However, I am trying to figure out what to do in an asynchronous case. How can I let OpenSSL know that we are not ready to verify client cert yet and it needs to wait until we acquire proper CA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function `SSL_CTX_set_cert_cb` to set a callback and if you return in the callback -1 then the handshake got paused.

The handshake isn't terminate and either isn't complete.

The moment when you are ready to continue the handshake you can call `SSL_accept` again.